# Issue with Excel Pivot table

Tags: excel, pivot, slicers

I have a pivot table in Excel which is connected to 3 slicers [Dep Slicer, Rep slicer, Date slicer].

I created custom list to sort the pivot table in order of Rep1, Rep2, Rep3 ..... Rep40, this works perfectly well but I do notice that when the report is being emailed out the users and the users use the slicers this change the order of the Rep slicer and the order of the pivot table

Can anyone help please.

I want the slicers not to change the order when they are being used and also the pivot table not to change when slicers are being used.

Comment: Custom lists are specific to an excel installation, not a workbook.

Comment: StackOverflow is not a code writing service. Please, provide your current code and describe what was wrong with it. You may also check [How much research effort is expected of Stack Overflow users](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/261592/how-much-research-effort-is-expected-of-stack-overflow-users)?

Comment: @Rory, Thank you for your response.  Yes I understand, but how does this explains another report I created a custom list for the sorting is working perfectly fine and the same users are not having any issues with the sorting when using the slicers and pivot tables

Comment: @WillieCheng I am aware StackOverflow is not a code writing, if you read my question attentively you would have noticed that I did not ask for any code to be written. I have an issue which I have also included the actions I took to solve but not working then I put it here to ask for help. Thank you I believe I have explained the issue but If you need a screenshot or further information I believe you can ask me to provide you with more clarification. Thank you

Comment: I couldn't tell you why other ones work.